# Metadata API : How to get the translated values of picklists of my object

Tags: api, picklist, metadata, translation

Wanna get the translated values of picklists of my object? How can I get them in Apex.

I tried using Metadata APi but invain. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Do you need all the possible translations, or just those for the session user?
If you just want them for the current user then you could retrieve the Schema.PicklistEntry list fro the field and then use [getLabel()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm#apex_Schema_PicklistEntry_getLabel) to get the transalation. There is also [toLabel()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm) that you can use in a SOQL query.

Answer (score 8):

In the Metadata API [CustomFieldTranslation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm) has a picklistValues field of type [`PicklistValueTranslation[]`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm#pickListValueTranslation). It has a masterLabel and translation string.

So your package.xml for the retrieve call would be something like:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
```

You will get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<!-- SNIP... -->
<fields>
    <name>LeadSource</name>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Advertisement</masterLabel>
        <translation>Anzeige</translation>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Customer Event</masterLabel>
        <translation>Kundenveranstaltung</translation>
    </picklistValues>
```

> I am trying to build a custom wizard where user can load a file and save the records. I need to check if the translated picklist values are correct and then save them back into database

You can get the translated picklist values directly in Apex without having to go via the Metadata API.

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = 
    SomeSobject.SomePicklistField__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
for (Schema.PicklistEntry pe: picklistValues) {
    system.debug('PicklistEntry Value:' + pe.getValue() + ' Translated Label:' + pe.getLabel());
}
```

Comment: I am trying to build a custom wizard where user can load a file and save the records. I need to check if the translated picklist values are correct and then save them back into database.

Comment: @CharanVuyyuru You can use the Schema.PicklistEntry metadata to get the translated picklist values for the current user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If we do a Field Describe on Picklist field, will the labels of picklist values are retrieved based on User Language?

Comment: @CharanVuyyuru I believe so, yes. The results to Schema.PicklistEntry.getLabel() should be for the current users language. You could test this quickly with the code sample I've given in anonymous apex. Just swap out the sObject and field names.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I'm trying this solution and I'm getting all the languages values in english, even if the user language is set to another language, do we have any other way to enforce this in apex to get the values from a specific language?

Comment: @pfernandez That's odd. Maybe ask a new question with the details of what you are trying to do. Feel free to reference back to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include object in package.xml.

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: I think this answer is of limited value because to me it looks like a less detailed version of the existing answer (which was made 5 years ago). Similar answers can be fine, but I like to see something to distinguish them (a different perspective/approach, additional information, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the latest change or not. Buit to get the Translation value for the picklist you have to include 'CustomObject' along with 'CustomObjectTranslation' to get the Translation value for the picklist.

The first answer by @Daniel Ballinger only showing the `<name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>` which didn't worked for me.
This fetched the respective files without the Translation values.

But to actually get the Translation value I have to use this package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">   <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
```

55.0

Comment: See Mukesh Saxena's answer - or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a clean solution, as Salesforce does not provide generic Apex methods for this. But this article describes a workaround that might be helpful: https://smartupload.medium.com/salesforce-tricks-how-to-retrieve-picklist-translations-in-any-language-programatically-1566fd91dc24

With this approach you don’t need the Metadata Api at all.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.