# How to retrieve translations using Metadata API?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, translation, package.xml

I'm trying to deploy the work that was done via `Rename Tabs and Labels` and `Translation Workbench` using Workbench and the Metadata API.

According to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/50796/10278), my package.xml should look like

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
```

which is what I did.

However, when deploying this to my target org, I notice the work done in Translation Workbench has not been deployed. When I check out the files in the objectTranslations folder, I see they only contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <caseValues>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Verkoopproces</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <plural>true</plural>
        <value>Verkoopprocessen</value>
    </caseValues>
    <gender>Feminine</gender>
</CustomObjectTranslation>
```

which is basically what was done via Rename Tabs and Labels.

What am I missing? How do I also get my **translated custom fields, picklist values etc.** in there?

Comment: Do any of the items that appear over to the right in the "Related" list help?

Comment: @KeithC I checked those, but as far as I see, they indicate that what I did should just work :-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include your objects in that package.xml and you will be golden. Here is what your package.xml should look like:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>AssistantProgress</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>CaseMilestone</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>ContractLineItem</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordItem</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordSet</members>
        <members>Entitlement</members>
        <members>EntitlementContact</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>FeedItem</members>
        <members>ForecastingAdjustment</members>
        <members>ForecastingCategoryMapping</members>
        <members>ForecastingOwnerAdjustment</members>
        <members>ForecastingQuota</members>
        <members>ForecastingTypeToCategory</members>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>LiveAgentSession</members>
        <members>LiveChatTranscript</members>
        <members>LiveChatTranscriptEvent</members>
        <members>LiveChatTranscriptSkill</members>
        <members>LiveChatVisitor</members>
        <members>Macro</members>
        <members>MacroAction</members>
        <members>MacroInstruction</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityCompetitor</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>Pricebook2</members>
        <members>PricebookEntry</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Question</members>
        <members>QuickText</members>
        <members>Quote</members>
        <members>QuoteLineItem</members>
        <members>Reply</members>
        <members>ServiceContract</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>SocialPersona</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>StreamingChannel</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>Territory2</members>
        <members>Territory2Model</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>UserProvisioningRequest</members>
        <members>UserTerritory2Association</members>
        <members>WorkBadge</members>
        <members>WorkBadgeDefinition</members>
        <members>WorkThanks</members>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

You may not need all the standard objects that I have listed here but this is what I have found works best.